# Apache Storm - log4j2 is printing its own log all the time even I turn off the root logger

Tags: java, log4j, apache-storm, log4j2

In my Storm APP, every time I run I now get these lines from console:

```
2018-01-17 18:38:30,417 main DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=D:\Desarrollo\workspaces\oxygen_main\StormAcustat\target\classes\log4j2.xml]
2018-01-17 18:38:30,426 main DEBUG Installed script engines
2018-01-17 18:38:31,172 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_144, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
2018-01-17 18:38:31,172 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 112 plugins
2018-01-17 18:38:31,173 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2018-01-17 18:38:31,185 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
2018-01-17 18:38:31,189 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2018-01-17 18:38:31,214 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
2018-01-17 18:38:31,255 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(D:\Desarrollo\workspaces\oxygen_main\StormAcustat\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2018-01-17 18:38:31,255 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 41 plugins
2018-01-17 18:38:31,259 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
2018-01-17 18:38:31,282 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="SYSTEM_OUT", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n), name="Console", Configuration(D:\Desarrollo\workspaces\oxygen_main\StormAcustat\target\classes\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2018-01-17 18:38:31,283 main DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2018-01-17 18:38:31,284 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
```

I have configured the `log4j2.xml` to make Storm redirect its log into different log files, and it is working:

```
<Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.storm" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Storm"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.storm.kafka" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Storm-Kafka"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ZooKeeper"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Storm-ZooKeeper"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="TestMain" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="TestMain"/>
        </Logger>
        <!-- these lines don't work -->
        <Logger name="org.apache.logging.log4j" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Storm-logging"/> 
        </Logger>
        <Root level="OFF">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
```

But I still get these logs from the console. I want to eliminate it with `log4j` or `log4j2` configuration.

I have checked the logs, and seeing that these logs seem to come from `org.apache.logging.log4j` itself, not from any other Storm classes, because the log files of `org.apache.storm`, `org.apache.storm.kafka` and so on, don't include these lines, and checking the source code, `PluginManager {} found {} plugins` is seen in the class:

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager.class
```

It is inside one of the dependency, `log4j-core-2.8.2.jar`.

So, it seems that the console prints the logs from `log4j`, not from Storm.

How to prevent that? As you can see, I have turned off root logger and I have these lines, but they don't work:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.logging.log4j" level="info">
    <AppenderRef ref="Storm-logging"/> 
</Logger>
```

EDIT: My `log4j2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="TestMain" fileName="D:\Proyectos\Storm\test\TestMain.log" filePattern="D:\Proyectos\Storm\test\TestMain.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
            bufferedIO="true" immediateFlush="true" append="true" ignoreExceptions="false"> <!-- bufferedIO: large performance improvement -->
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="Storm" fileName="D:\Proyectos\Storm\test\Storm.log" filePattern="D:\Proyectos\Storm\test\Storm.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
            bufferedIO="true" immediateFlush="true" append="true" ignoreExceptions="false"> <!-- bufferedIO: large performance improvement -->
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="Storm-Kafka" fileName="D:\Proyectos\Storm\test\Storm-Kafka.log" filePattern="D:\Proyectos\Storm\test\Storm-Kafka.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
            bufferedIO="true" immediateFlush="true" append="true" ignoreExceptions="false"> <!-- bufferedIO: large performance improvement -->
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="ZooKeeper" fileName="D:\Proyectos\Storm\test\ZooKeeper.log" filePattern="D:\Proyectos\Storm\test\ZooKeeper.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
            bufferedIO="true" immediateFlush="true" append="true" ignoreExceptions="false"> <!-- bufferedIO: large performance improvement -->
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="Storm-ZooKeeper" fileName="D:\Proyectos\Storm\test\Storm-ZooKeeper.log" filePattern="D:\Proyectos\Storm\test\Storm-ZooKeeper.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
            bufferedIO="true" immediateFlush="true" append="true" ignoreExceptions="false"> <!-- bufferedIO: large performance improvement -->
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="Storm-logging" fileName="D:\Proyectos\Storm\test\Storm-logging.log" filePattern="D:\Proyectos\Storm\test\Storm-logging.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
            bufferedIO="true" immediateFlush="true" append="true" ignoreExceptions="false"> <!-- bufferedIO: large performance improvement -->
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.storm" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Storm"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.storm.kafka" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Storm-Kafka"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ZooKeeper"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Storm-ZooKeeper"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="TestMain" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="TestMain"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.logging.log4j" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Storm-logging"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="OFF">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post your complete `log4j2` configuration file or starting few lines of that file ?

Comment: OK, question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logs that are getting printed are of `log4j2` because you have enabled `debug` level logging of `log4j2`.

To turn off this detailed logging, change `status` attribute of `Configuration` element in your configuration to `warn` or `error` -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
...
```

Rest should remain same.

Log4j2 [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#troubleshooting) describes about this logging in detail -

> **From log4j-2.9 onward**
>
> From log4j-2.9 onward, log4j2 will print all internal logging to the
>   console if system property `log4j2.debug` is defined (with any or no
>   value).
>
> **Prior to log4j-2.9**
>
> Prior to log4j-2.9, there are two places where internal logging can be
>   controlled:
>
> If the configuration file is found correctly, log4j2 internal status
>   logging can be controlled by setting `<Configuration status="trace">` in
>   the configuration file. This will display detailed log4j2-internal log
>   statements on the console about what happens during the configuration
>   process. This may be useful to trouble-shoot configuration issues. By
>   default the status logger level is WARN, so you only see notifications
>   when there is a problem.
>
> If the configuration file is not found correctly, you can still enable
>   log4j2 internal status logging by setting system property
>   `-Dorg.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level=TRACE`.

Comment: Yes, it is the way.... but the doc never mentions that... I spent all afternoon reading it. Now it is gone, thanks. Any Log4j doc references? I believe not....

Comment: So, where do these lines go? No way to print them into a file right? Because I don't see ways to redirect it.

Comment: I added reference for log4j documentation. Currently, there is no way to print these logs in file.

Comment: Perfect answer.